# How can I save a single firebase entry within a set of nested data?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I understand that it's best practice to denormalize my dataset, but there are some times when it just doesn't make sense. In these cases, how should I be saving nested object properties back to Firebase?

e.g. given a structure like:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children">

        <input ng-model="child.property">
        <button ng-click="saveToFirebase(child)">Save</button>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="grandchild in child.children">
                <input ng-model="grandchild.property">
                <button ng-click="saveToFirebase(grandchild)">Save</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Assuming `parent` is an instance of `$FirebaseObject`, how should I be saving changes to the grandchild object? Should I be loading `grandchild` as a Firebase reference/instance/object/array somehow? How would I do that instead?

It seems to me this basic functionality should be... basic, but I can't figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is done with ref.child() & ref.set() methods.

You can chain methods together, e.g:

```
var parent = new Firebase('url');
parent.child('child').child('grandChild').child('greatGrandChild').set('change');
```

Here's the official docs:

 .child() - https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/child.html

 .set() - https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html

Comment: I'm dealing with the `angularFire` library specifically, not the standalone JS FB library. Naturally I could drop down to the lower level stuff, but I'd hoped to use the `$firebase` service's built-in extensions. Either way, this wouldn't necessarily solve the problem since `.child()` returns a firebase reference, which isn't enumerable via `ng-repeat`

Comment: @MurraySmith AngularFire is not a built-in extension. It's a bindings library for synchronizing collections and objects. The appropriate answer here is to drop down to the API level. Also, [don't nest data just because you can](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html), this data structure is a mess.

Comment: Okay, how would I accomplish this with properly flattened data and by dropping down to the API level?